# MySQL commands in vb code are not working

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I've been trying to create a login page that will check if you're an administrator or a customer in my SQL data source. I am not sure why it can't understand the `MySQLCommand`s. I added `MySql.Data` in the references but this doesn't seem to work.

This is where for example: `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` have blue underlinement.

```
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand '(strSQL, con)
```

Comment: What error (if any) do you get?

Comment: And if you right click them, is there a `Resolve` option?

Comment: @Steve Type 'MySQLComman' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Password is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySql. If you want to use a field with that name then everytime you use it in your code you should remember to put it between backticks:

```
 `password` = ...
```

Said that your code has serious problems. You should never concatenate strings coming from the user input to form a sql text. This leads to syntax errors caused by parsing problem and to Sql Injection attacks. You shoul use a parameterized query like this

```
   strSQL = "SELECT name FROM employer WHERE (login=@login AND `password`=@pwd"
   Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, con)
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strUser 
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd",MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strPaswoord
   con.Open()
   If cmd.ExecuteScalar() = Nothing Then
      ....
```

Finally you should also change the way you get your data because you want to minimize the trips to access the database for performance reason. You should SELECT both the Name and the EMail with a single query and use an MySqlDataReader to get the data.

Other problems present in your code are the lack of appropriate using statement around the connection and the security problem caused by a possible clear text password stored in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'm new in all this and am trying to keep it simple so I didn't think of how to stop sqlinjections. THis is also why my code is probably not very clean.
But for example:
 `Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()`
shows that `MySqlConnection` is not defined.

Comment: Did you add the reference to the MySql.Data.dll library and then did you add an Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient ? These steps are basic if you want to use the library to access an MySql database

Comment: YES! I forgot MySql.Data.MySqlClient at the top! I jsut figured that out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@GSerg asked me if I could right click and resolve.
I tried that but that was not an option.
After messing around with the error it appears that I had to write at top:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

I also had to add backticks when I used the word password for MySQL as @Steve reminded me.

Thank you for your help!